# Prove $f(x)=\int _0^\infty |x+t\sin t| e^{-t}dt$ reaches its minimum

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is an exercise of a calculus homework, but I have no idea how to deal with it:

Let
$$f(x)=\int _0^\infty |x+t\sin t| e^{-t}dt$$
be defined as a function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove it reaches its minimum.

Could anyone give me some hint? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hint: $f$ is a continuous function with $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Extreme value theorem?

Comment: @Gerd Ah! That’s the key point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)$ is continuous as it satisfies
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-t}\,dt =|x-y|$$
We have $$f(0)<\int\limits_0^\infty te^{-t}\,dt=1$$ Next $$\displaylines{f(x)>\int\limits_0^{|x|}(|x|-t)e^{-t}\,dt =\int\limits_0^{|x|}te^{t-|x|}\,dt\\ =e^{-|x|} \int\limits_0^{|x|}te^{t}\,dt\ge e^{-|x|} (|x|-1)e^{|x|}=|x|-1}$$
Hence $f(\pm 2)>1.$ Therefore the minimal value is attained in the interval $[-2,2].$

Comment: Thank you very much for the details! The main idea was outlined by Gerd above.